# goto não segura valor de variáveis

Tags: c++

Estou fazendo um código simples e estou usando o `goto`

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int exemplo(void);

int main()
{
    exemplo();
}

exemplo(){
comeco:
{
int numero;
numero = 0;
goto fim;
}
fim:
{
cout << numero;
}
}
```

mas diz que o `numero` não foi declarado no escope e as vezes o código só assume um valor aleatório para ele, alguma solução? (eu tenho vários `goto` nesse código)

Comment: Mas este código é para testar o `goto` ? É que eu não vejo motivo para usar `goto` aqui.

Comment: Se a reposta lhe foi útil, não deixe de marcá-la, veja: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O escopo em que está declarando `int numero;`(`comeco`), é diferente do escopo em que usa `numero` (`fim`).

Assim você precisará declara-la em um escopo acima:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int exemplo(void);

int main()
{
    exemplo();
}

int exemplo() {
    int numero;
    comeco:
    {
        numero = 0;
        goto fim;
    }
    fim:
    {
        cout << numero;
    }
}
```